# Extract Data from URL VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am trying to get Addresses Data from URL but facing some error. I am just beginner in VBA, i did not Understand where is proble[image]m in my code. wish somebody can help me to get right solution.

here I attached Image and also my VBA code

here is my Code

```
Public Sub IE_GetLink()
Dim sResponse As String, HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String
Dim Re As Object

Set HTML = New HTMLDocument
Set Re = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
'On Error Resume Next

url = "http://markexpress.co.in/network1.aspx?Center=360370&Tmp=1656224682265"

        
        With Re
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        End With

        
        Dim Title As Object
        With HTML
            .body.innerHTML = sResponse
          Title = .querySelectorAll("#colspan")(0).innerText
        End With
        MsgBox Title
End Sub
```

Please help me ...

Comment: For a start, you could explain what "some error" means ...

Comment: facing error Block veritable not set , Title = .querySelectorAll("#colspan")(0).innerText

Comment: Have you checked the value of HTML? You have not used/"filled" it.

Comment: @shrotter Sir Please I don't know how to Used Filled it.. Please can you help me in codeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things.

What is wrong with your code:

1. Title should be a string as you are attempting to assign the return of .innerText to it. You have declared it as an object which would require SET keyword (and the removal of the .innerText accessor).
2. Colspan is an attribute not an id so your css selector list is incorrect.

Furthermore, looking at what the page actually does, there is a request for an additional document which actually has the info you need. You need to take the centre ID you already have and change the URI you make a request to.

Then, you want only the first td in the target table. Change your CSS selector list to target that.

---

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim HTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim re As Object

    Set HTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set re = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    Dim url As String
    Dim response As String
    
    url = "http://crm.markerp.in/NetworkDetail.aspx?Center=360370&Tmp="
    
    With re
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        response = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim info As String
    
    With HTML
        .body.innerHTML = response
         info = .querySelector("#tblDisp td").innerText
    End With
    
    MsgBox info
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one QHarr. I saw this a few hours ago. I made a few attempts to resolve this, but nothing that I tried actually worked. Good stuff!!